# captured images not reflecting in folder

Tags: python, opencv

i wrote a code to capture the images from opencv and save the images in folder within the directory but my programm reflecting the images in folder after the stopping the run code. i want the images should reflect in the folder after capturing the images only and then it should go to click another image

```
import cv2
import os
import time

save_folder = 'row_photos'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
interval = 10
start_time = int(time.time())


while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    belt = frame[209:327, 137:530]  # cordinates of the belt
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(belt, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # to detect th eframe we will change the color to gray

    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_frame, 80, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # inorder to ignore bachground part we will give some threshould value to it

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        # calculate Area
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

        cv2.rectangle(belt, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(belt, str(area), (x, y), 1, 1, (0, 255, 0))

    cv2.imshow("belt", belt)

    elapsed_time = int(time.time()) - start_time
    
    if elapsed_time >= interval:
        image_name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + ".jpg"
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, image_name)
        cv2.imwrite(save_path, belt)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        # cv2.imshow(save_path)
        print("Image saved as", save_path)
        start_time = time.time()
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllwindows()
```

here is code

i tried using thread still not working

Comment: Btw `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` is correct. (W not w)

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` and then make sure you understand relative paths

Comment: you should also check the return value of `cv2.imwrite`, which will let you know if the image was succesfully written or not. 
However, your code seems to work fine for me, as long as the `row_photos` directory is provided. Can you be more specific about the problem you are facing ?

Comment: in terminal its showing output of 'print("Image saved as", save_path)' which is correct  , at the same time i want to see my saved image in folder too but its showing all images in folder after terminating the code.